# The "learning" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Why do we have the [learning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) tag? The whole purpose of this site is learning. Usually it's used to refer specifically to beginners learning to play, but I'm not sure it's useful to have a tag for that (no matter what the tag is called).

The current tag wiki also doesn't help clear up how it should be used as it currently just states:

> Learning is the act of acquiring or developing skills and knowledge.

Comment: Good question, this is somewhat related: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/65/133

Answer (score 3):

[learning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) is clearly inappropriate when used as a **meta tag**.  Meta tags describe the question, instead of the content of the question.  You're correct that all questions are ideally about learning something from the answers, but using the tag for that reason is incorrect.  Using it when the asker has a question about learning itself is appropriate.

As you mentioned, it's usually used to refer specifically to beginners learning to play. I've also seen it used for questions about learning new styles or techniques.  I think this is useful.  A piano teacher who joins the site might, for example, search `[piano] [learning]` so that they can help some people out.  An intermediate musician might search `[learning]` so they can help out beginners with the basics, since they're not able to help experts.

In short, I see no problem with this tag if it's used appropriately.  Updating the tag wiki to reflect its proper usage might be a good idea.  And if a question is tagged wrong, please re-tag :)

Comment: We have the [beginners tag](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) (not sure if it was here this early in the site). Your argument seems better for that tag than the learning tag.

Comment: This answer makes a lot of sense to me. Would "learning process" be an adequate tag synonym? Does that capture the meaning you're conveying here, and is it not too colloquial?